# function in vuejs is executing more then once

Tags: vuejs2

I'm beginner in vuejs,
In my template I want to show floor manager which is defined in another array managers[],hence I'm using function instead of variable.
But this function is running three times,I don't know why

here is my template

```
<div class="user-information containt-box shadow">
    <div class="row mb-5">

        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h4>Basic Information</h4>
        <div class="user-search-result-table mt-5">
            <div class="form-detail no-gutters row">
            <strong class="label col-sm-5">Floor Manager: </strong>
            <span class="value col-sm-7">{{floorManager()}}</span>
            </div>
```

An here is my method,

```
floorManager(){
    let floorManager= this.managers.filter(event => {
         return event.id == this.manager_id;      
         })
    return floorManager[0].first_name+' ' + 
floorManager[0].last_name;
},
```

Please tell me if there is any better way of doing this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. In your case, you should use computed property https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html . It is not supposed to rerender it a few times.

Comment: As a sidenote, it's better to use Array.find to, well, find an element - instead of Array.filter, which goes over all the elements even after locating the one.

Comment: How do I pass parameter to this property if I want to use it multiple times.

Comment: And please tell me why method gets executed more then once.Thank you

Comment: Can't able to get manager array and manager_id inside computed, values assigned to them by axios when mounted

Answer (score 0):

The function will be evaluated every time `this.managers` changes.  That value must be getting mutated in other parts of your code.

Also,

Use `find` instead of `filter`.  The returned value won’t be an array.

If this is not a computed property method, it should be. Move it to `computed` section and remove the `()` from the template.

Answer (score 0):

Try using computed properties, instead of methods. (Just pull that function from methods and paste it under computed)

```
computed:{
    floorManager(){
         let floorManager= this.managers.filter(event => {
             return event.id == this.manager_id;      
         })
        return floorManager[0].first_name+' ' + floorManager[0].last_name;
},
```

and in template just replace the method call to getter(property name)

```
  ...
  <strong class="label col-sm-5">Floor Manager: </strong>
  <span class="value col-sm-7">{{floorManager}}</span>
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended with precaution like this

```
floorManager() {
            let floorManager = this.managers.filter(event => {
                return event.id == this.floor.manager_id;
            })
            if(floorManager.length>0)
            return floorManager[0].first_name + ' ' + 
floorManager[0].last_name;
            else
            return '';
        }
```

By using computed property it is executing once

```
computed: {
    hloorManager(){
       let  floorManager= this.managers.find(event => {
       return event.id == this.manager_id;      
       })
      console.log('qse');
      return floorManager.first_name+' ' + floorManager.last_name;
  },
  ...
}
```

but still Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined